# How to save generated image (from imagecreatefromjepeg) in the server (not in the PC)?

Tags: php

i am asked to create a from that will ask for text inputs and a photo to be uploaded. then create an image wherein those are displayed. the generated image must then be saved to the server (not using database). i have a code here that successfully generates the image (i used imagejpeg and imagecreatefromjpeg in this case. but then i still need to save it to the server with the file extension .jpg.  i also need to give it a unique name.

i tried using **header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="image.jpg"');** but what it does is save it to the PC not in the server. below is my code. please feel frre to edit it. also, please leave some comments so that i can understand it and not just do copy paste. thank you so much in advance for you help. i really need to make it working by now. thanks again

```
    //for textbox input
$title = $_POST['title'];
$story = "My super story begins with" . $_POST['story'] . " My task was " . $_POST['task'] ." With the super power of ". $_POST['power'] ." I solved it by ". $_POST['solve'] ." The result was". $_POST['result'];


//header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="image.jpg"'); //this works for saving img to PC or downloading it force .jpg ext
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');


$upload = $uploadFilename; //this is for getting the uploaded file
$im = imagecreatefromjpeg("bg2.jpg");
$img2 = imagecreatefromjpeg($upload);
$black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
$font = 'arialbi.ttf';
$font2 = 'ariali.ttf';

imagettftext($im, 24, 0, $width_sum, 300, $black, $font, $title);


$newtext = wordwrap($story, 35, "\n", true);
$newertext2 = explode  ("\n", $newtext);
imagettftext($im, 8, 0, 300, 362, $black, $font, $story);
imagettftext($im, 8, 0, 300, 374, $black, $font2,$story);
imagettftext($im, 8, 0, 300, 386, $black, $font, $story);
imagettftext($im, 8, 0, 300, 398, $black, $font2, $story);
imagettftext($im, 8, 0, 300, 410, $black, $font, $story);
imagettftext($im, 8, 0, 300, 422, $black, $font2, $story);
imagettftext($im, 8, 0, 300, 434, $black, $font,$story);
imagettftext($im, 8, 0, 300, 446, $black, $font2, $story);
imagettftext($im, 8, 0, 300, 458, $black, $font,$story);
imagettftext($im, 8, 0, 300, 570, $black, $font2, $story);
imagettftext($im, 8, 0, 300, 582, $black, $font, $story);


imagecopymerge($im, $img2, 10, 350, 0, 0, imagesx($img2), imagesy($img2), 100);
imagejpeg($im, null, 100);


//closing for imagejpeg
imagejpeg($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, as the manual of [imagejpeg](http://php.net/imagejpeg) says: the second argument is the filename where you want to store the image.

Comment: the null in my code. so can it be something like // make a note of the current working directory, relative to root.
$directory_self = str_replace(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '', $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);

// make a note of the directory that will recieve the uploaded files //i made it as the same directory where the .php file is
$uploadsDirectory = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $directory_self;

Comment: Indeed the NULL in your code. If you want the directory of the current file you can use the constant `__DIR__` (http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) for example: `$fullPath = __DIR__ . '/' . $filename`, or use `dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'])` if you have used includes and want the directory of your 'main' script

Comment: i have tried imagejpeg($im, "/home3/birdieon/public_html/Folder/uploader/uploader/gen_img.jpg" , 100); yes it works. but i want to try your suggestion "dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'])" so i can be safe that whaever the folder name is, it will still be saved together with the php script. i will try it now :)

Comment: oops! how can i append the directory so it will have the filename "gen_img.jpg"? thanks :)

Comment: Good to hear it works, use string concatenation with a dot: `dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']) . '/gen_img.jpg';` or `dirname(..) . '/' . $filename;`. Also try to decrease the jpg-quality, you use 100, but 80 or 90 is sufficient in most cases and saves you a lot of disk-space. Try some different values and find out what works best for you.

Comment: i made it to something like this

    $img_name = "/gen_image.jpg";
    $img_dir =dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']) . $img_name;
    imagejpeg($im, $img_dir , 80);

Comment: thank you so much! i will accept your answer now again thank you @Peter van der Wal for your help. :)

Comment: Thank you also to you @Anton for you help. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try imagejpeg($im, "/PATH/IMAGE_NAME.jpeg")

This should help.

Comment: i tried:
imagejpeg($im, "/home3/birdieon/public_html/Amadeus/uploader/uploader/gen_img.jpg" , 100); and it worked! i wonder how can i make the IMAGE_NAME.jpg not display in the screen yet it still get saved to the server.